# Getting error Trying to get property of non-object in simple html dom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

here is the code which I am using to extract data:

```
ini_set("user_agent","Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; U; Edition Campaign 21; en-GB) Presto/2.7.62 Version/11.00");

$html14=file_get_html("https://www.gamesrocket.com/battlefield-1.html");

$title14 = $html14->find('span.price',0)->children(0)->plaintext;

for ($i=0; $i <sizeof($title14) ; $i++) { 
    # code...

    if($title14[$i]){
        echo $title14[$i]->plaintext;
        $a13=$title14[$i]->plaintext;
    }
    else{

        echo "problem";
    }

}
```

Here I am trying to extract price from the given page but all I am getting this error : `Trying to get property of non-object` .I am using simple html dom for extracting data

Answer (score 0):

because  $title14 is string and not object,
you can `var_dump($title14);` to know the type of it.

```
ini_set("user_agent","Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; U; Edition Campaign 21; en-GB) Presto/2.7.62 Version/11.00");



$html14=file_get_html("https://www.gamesrocket.com/battlefield-1.html");

 $title14 = $html14->find('span.price',0)->children(0)->plaintext;
  for ($i=0; $i <sizeof($title14) ; $i++) { 

   if($title14[$i]){
   echo $title14[$i];
   $a13=$title14[$i];
   }
  else{

    echo "problem";
}

}
```

Comment: So how should I echo a string now?

Comment: The code which you gave me displays only 1 but I want to display 41.11.